# Avoid punctuation as delimiter in list

Tags: sas

I have a list (of frequencies) that I want to loop through. Example list:

```
%let Freq_list = min5 min2 sec60.31 sec30;
```

As default SAS treat the punctation in "sec60.31" as a delimiter. How do I avoid using punctuation (".") as delimiter in the list?

I want to loop through this list of frequencies, and then want "sec60.31" to become one such member to extract from the list.

More code (part of program):

```
%let n_f = %sysfunc(countw(&freqlist));

%do I_f=1 %to &n_f;
%let freq = %scan(&freqlist,&I_f);
%let freqtext = %scan(&freqtextlist,&I_f);
proc timeseries data=[datafile] out= [datafile]_&freqtext.;
where weekday between 2 and 6;
id datetime interval=&freq accumulate=last setmissing=missing align=beg start = '01jan1999.00:05'dt end = '01dec2014.00:00'dt;
var price;
run;
%end;
```

The result is that it runs PROC TIMESERIES with "interval = sec60", and then produce the following error when it comes to the "31"-part:

```
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "FREQ".
1     31
      --
      22
      200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a format name.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

The counter &n_f indicates that the COUNTW-function treat "." as a delimter so I guess I both need the COUNTW-function and the SCAN-function to recognize the delimiter.

As you may have noticed I have another list to use in file-names etc.

```
%let Freq_textlist = min5 min2 min1 sec30;
```

One solution for my problem could be to get counter &n_f from this list (which is of equal length), and change my freq_list to:

```
%let Freq_list = min5@min2@sec60.31@sec30;
```

and use %scan with delimiter-paramter, as in:

```
%let freq = %scan(&freqlist,&I_f,@);
```

This works without having to deal with how COUNTW can recognize "." as not a delimiter.

Comment: Could you post the code and the result?

Comment: have you tried using %str?
%let freq_list = %str(min5 min2 sec60.31 sec30);
also how do you loop through frequencies? with %scan you can set a delimiter, which is the requested result?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop on the elements in a macro variable with the `%scan()` macro function you can explicitly specify the delimiter(s) as third argument.

The following statement will output 'sec30':

```
%put %scan(&Freq_list.,4,' ');
```

Comment: Thisis the solution I would go for as well. `countw` also has a delimeter argument, `%let n_f = %sysfunc(countw(&freqlist, ' '));`, returns 4 instead of 5 elements as in the original code.

Comment: I believe you actually want to use `%str( )` as the third parameter (with a space character inbetween the brackets in `%str( )` ).  Your solution would also delimit on a single quote character which is an undesired side-effect.  This is probably why the OP had trouble figuring it out to begin with, to pass a space as a parameter you need to wrap it in a macro quoting function such as `%str()` for it to be recognized.  Using single quotes also adds to the misconception that strings need to be quoted when working with macros.

Comment: @RobertPenridge; Nice, I have not thought about that. So used to it from other programming languages I suppose.